# regex search and sub

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find a faster way to replace every username with the string kittycat.

```
2018 Aug 01 01:59:59 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4625): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: peter.parker: no domain: my.own.domain: An account failed to log on.

2018 Aug 02 01:59:59 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(4624): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: 4dministr4t0r: my-log: still.my.domain: An account was successfully logged on.

2018 Aug 03 01:59:59 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4768): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: my.other.domain: A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested.
```

(regex is assuming - no username contains a ':')

__My_Current_Solution

```
import re

regex = '^.+Auditing\:\s+(?P<username>.+?(?=\:))'
result = re.search(regex, string)
username = result.group('username')
result=re.sub(username,kittycat,string)
print result
```

Comment: Why use `re.search`? `re.sub(r'(Auditing:\s*)[^:]+', r'\1{}'.format(kittycat),s)`. If `kittycat` is just a string, not a variable, the replacement becomes even simpler: `r'\1kittycat'`.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<=Auditing: ).*?(?=: )', 'kittycat', s)`

Comment: Thank your for the fast reply.

Comment: What if I would like to hash the username ? ,r'\1{}'.format(lambda m: hashlib.sha512(m.group().encode()).hexdigest()),s)  "<function <lambda> at 0x00000000046E6748>" would be the output

Comment: You do not need `,r'\1{}'.` then. `re.sub(r'(Auditing:\s*)([^:]+)', lambda m: m.group(1) + hashlib.sha512(m.group(2).encode()).hexdigest(), s)`.

Comment: works like a charm - thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re, hashlib
s = "2018 Aug 01 01:59:59 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4625): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: peter.parker: no domain: my.own.domain: An account failed to log on."
print(re.sub(r'(Auditing:\s*)([^:]+)', lambda m: m.group(1) + hashlib.sha512(m.group(2).encode()).hexdigest(), s))
# => 2018 Aug 01 01:59:59 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4625): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: 2dd95ce5e79de5cedbb3f50b635b9b9125c19464b15938a242aec0db227cfb408570837b12912db97704cac96d22d9fda9f140ea63adf17959c334570ccc8a41: no domain: my.own.domain: An account failed to log on.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vfx9sC)

**Pattern details**

- `(Auditing:\s*)` - Capturing group 1: `Auditing:` substring and then 0+ whitespaces
- `([^:]+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more chars other than `:`.

In the replacement lambda expression, Group 1 is referred to with `m.group(1)` and Group 2 value is referred to with `m.group(2)`.